# Why organic reaction mechanisms so popular

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Why are organic reaction mechanisms so much more popular than inorganic mechanisms? When I come to think of it, what is a reaction mechanism? How can we use an arrow? Is it a rough approximation of the real picture i.e. the true quantum mechanical picture?

Comment: No, inorganic reaction mechanism are also popular: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10959/inorganic-chemistry-reaction-mechanisms/15882?r=SearchResults#15882

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125767/is-organic-chemistry-mechanisms-limited-to-organic-chemistry?r=SearchResults

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65044/how-do-organic-chemistry-mechanisms-become-accepted?r=SearchResults

Comment: There is a simple answer: there are a lot more organic reactions because there are a lot more organic compounds than inorganic ones. This is a simple result of the enormous variety of molecules than can be built from carbon skeletons. Nothing else in the periodic table comes close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the main types of reactions in inorganic chemistry (here I am only speaking of the common ones):

1. Redox reactions- These electron exchange reactions are often so fast, and so spontaneous, with K values of higher powers of 10. It hence becomes very difficult to have a 'mechanism' for them, as an important part of a mechanism is knowing what happened in the time the reaction was proceeding (the study of *T.S.*, reaction intermediates, etc.). Thus such fast reactions we say occur in a single step and do not have a mechanism. The truth is, that there are just so many reactions of this type, that this becomes a common misconception.
2. Ligand substitution reactions- These do have proper mechanisms in place and various concepts to decide what happens first, who leaves better, whos substitutes better, like [trans effect](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Organometallic_Chemistry/Fundamentals_of_Organometallic_Chemistry/The_trans%2F%2Fcis_Effects_and_Influences) to name one such concept.
3. Organometallic reactions- Well as the name suggests, they, of course, do have mechanisms, and I won't go in great detail as to what those mechanisms are, you can see it [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10959/inorganic-chemistry-reaction-mechanisms)

[Types of organometallic reactions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10959/inorganic-chemistry-reaction-mechanisms):

> Ligand dissociation / association
>   Reductive elimination / oxidative addition
>   Intramolecular insertion (e.g. CO migratory insertion) / elimination (e.g. β–hydride elimination)
>   Metallacycle processes (e.g. σ-bond metathesis)
>   Nucleophilic / electrophilic addition and abstraction are also possible, similar to organic chemistry.

4. Combination, displacement, double displacement- These are often so simple, that ion-exchange, etc. are the only things that happen in them. So they also most of the times do not have a mechanism.

Hence, the common misconception is that these reactions never have a mechanism, but as you can see, that is not entirely true, but in most curriculums of inorganic chemistry, you will not learn 2. and 3. at a basic level, hence it is fair to be having this misconception.

Answer (score 5):

I believe a similar question had been asked before. Most inorganic reactions take place in aqueous media in their ionic form, and the substrate is simply not complex enough to warrant a reaction mechanism. As far as I know, mechanisms do exist for [Coordination compound](http://chem.yonsei.ac.kr/chem/upload/CHE3103-01/125652642990718.pdf) reactions.

You might want to check out [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Arrow_Pushing_in_Inorganic_Chemistry.html) which explains inorganic mechanisms using the arrow-pushing mechanism seen in organic chemistry.